# How to add a processing string with js2xmlparser

Tags: javascript

I've looking at the docs and can't find it anywhere. Only other option I'm considering is doing some type of substring insertion to add it.

Example:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<?qbxml version='13.0'?>
<QBXML> ... </QBXML>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question a bit further? Providing examples on what you need would also help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any solution, so I ended up swapping out js2xmlparser for xml-js which has a very simple solution that you add to the js object for including a processing string or instruction:

```
instruction: "<?qbxml version='13.0' ?>"
```